# Get list of jobs which created via job-dsl and list of manual jobs

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-job-dsl

Part of the job was generated through job-dsl, but there is still part of the job that was created by manual. If Jenkins has a mechanism or api to get a list of all manual jobs.

I see that all jobs through job-dsl have a mark which job created them(seed job). Perhaps having received a list of all generated ones, you can take a list of all jobs and weed out manual ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JobDSL saves information about generated jobs in the `javaposse.jobdsl.plugin.ExecuteDslScripts.xml` file, example:

```xml
<?xml version='1.1' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<javaposse.jobdsl.plugin.DescriptorImpl plugin="job-dsl@1.77">
  <templateJobMap class="com.google.common.collect.HashMultimap" serialization="custom">
    <com.google.common.collect.HashMultimap>
      <default/>
      <int>8</int>
      <int>0</int>
    </com.google.common.collect.HashMultimap>
  </templateJobMap>
  <generatedJobMap class="concurrent-hash-map">
    <entry>
      <string>generated-job-name1</string>
      <javaposse.jobdsl.plugin.SeedReference>
        <seedJobName>job-which-created-it</seedJobName>
        <digest>hash1</digest>
      </javaposse.jobdsl.plugin.SeedReference>
    </entry>
    <entry>
      <string>generated-job-name2</string>
      <javaposse.jobdsl.plugin.SeedReference>
        <seedJobName>job-which-created-it</seedJobName>
        <digest>hash2</digest>
      </javaposse.jobdsl.plugin.SeedReference>
    </entry>
    ...
  </generatedJobMap>
</javaposse.jobdsl.plugin.DescriptorImpl>
```

If you parse the file and collect all `javaposse.jobdsl.plugin.DescriptorImpl/generatedJobMap/entry/string` values then you get a list of all generated jobs.

You can next get all jobs by using [Jenkins.get().getItems()](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/jenkins/model/Jenkins.html#getItems--), collect all names and at the end remove those which were found in the `javaposse.jobdsl.plugin.ExecuteDslScripts.xml` file.

---

EDIT:

The file keeps an XML representation of the `javaposse.jobdsl.plugin.DescriptorImpl` class. You can also get it programmatically: [Jenkins.get().getDescriptorByType(Class<?> type)](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/jenkins/model/Jenkins.html#getDescriptorByType-java.lang.Class-).

```
def jenkins = Jenkins.get()
def clazz = Class.forName('javaposse.jobdsl.plugin.DescriptorImpl', true, jenkins.pluginManager.uberClassLoader)
def descriptor = jenkins.getDescriptorByType(clazz)
descriptor.generatedJobMap // map with listed previously entries
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a way using the script console!

### TL;DR:

```
Jenkins.instance.jobNames.findAll {
    job = Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName(it)
    a = job.getAction(javaposse.jobdsl.plugin.actions.SeedJobAction.class)
    return a?.isConfigChanged()
}.each {
    println it
}
```

### Explanation

It took some digging (and I've no idea what I'm doing; maybe there's an easy way). I noticed that all the information I was looking for was readily available on the "front page" of jobs. Information here can be added via plugins. After searching the JobDsl code for the string "Seed job:" I came across [this file](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/blob/master/job-dsl-plugin/src/main/resources/javaposse/jobdsl/plugin/actions/SeedJobAction/jobMain.jelly), which is a [Jelly](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Basic+guide+to+Jelly+usage+in+Jenkins) file. After some guesswork I came up with the code above.

The `a` object has getters for the information you see accessed via the `it` object in the Jelly file, e.g. `getSeedJob()`. For checking whether the config changed you prefix it with `is` instead of `get`, presumably because it returns a boolean. If `a` is `null` then it was not generated by a seed job.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to automate: Jenkins has a detailed rest api where you can fetch information about jobs etc. You will get JSON objects back which then need to be interpreted.
https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/using/remote-access-api/

To check if the Api provides the information you need, you can use http://jenkins:8080/job/yourjob/api/json?pretty=true

Comment: Unfortunately this api doesn't provide information about generated or manual created jobs